# open an error log from bash

Tags: bash, shell, gedit, xdgutils

I have a script that records error while creating users.

At the last line of my script I open the file with the following command:

```
xdg-open "error.log"&
```

It open correctly, but I have the flwg error message:

```
(gedit:23228): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: La connexion est fermée
Error creating proxy: La connexion est fermée (g-io-error-quark, 18)
```

Comment: GTK applications are notorious for spewing lots of useless warnings to the console. I wouldn't be too concerned about it. You can send the warnings into a black hole with `2>/dev/null` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should run this as a root. So try this;

```
sudo -i
xdg-open "error.log"&
```

Or

```
ggksudo -l gedit error.log &
```